# Make existing non-writable and non-configurable property writable and configurable

Tags: javascript

Say I've got an object:

```
var agent = new Agent({name: 'James', type: 'secret', id: 007})
```

When I built the Agent class, I decided to make the id property immutable:

```
Object.defineProperty(Agent.prototype, 'id', {
    configurable: false,
    writable: false
})
```

But at some point I will want to mark the object for deletion. And because we can't actually delete `this`, I'm going to cripple the object by removing the `id` property instead. So I go to make the property writable again:

```
Object.defineProperty(agent, 'id', {
    configurable: true,
    writable: true
})
delete agent.id
```

But of course I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot redefine property: id
```

Because `id` already exists.

How can I make an *existing* non-writable property writable?

Comment: read http://webreflection.blogspot.in/2011/10/do-you-really-know-objectdefineproperty.html. It might help

Comment: Wat??? First of all, please [understand that `delete` does not mark an object for deletion](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/). And yor example is pretty incoherent: it makes the `.id` property of `Agent.prototype` (that was never defined anywhere) immutable, but then it goes on to configure the `.id` property of the `agent` instance. Would you please share what your `Agent` constructor does?

Comment: This is not a variable per se, this is a property of a larger class. If you really want to know, this is part of an SDK that deals with read-only or write-once properties of an API response. The intent was to allow properties to reflect the behavior of the API, rather than having misrepresented properties pollute the SDK instance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Modifying_a_property) says

> When the property already exists, Object.defineProperty() attempts to
>   modify the property according to the values in the descriptor and the
>   object's current configuration. If the old descriptor had its
>   configurable attribute set to false (the property is said to be
>   “non-configurable”), then no attribute besides writable can be
>   changed. If a property is non-configurable, its writable attribute can
>   only be changed to false.

In other words, you must set `configurable` to `true` in the first property definition if you want to modify the property definition (to be writable) later.

Note that you can go the other way (make  writable property non-writable) when `configurable` is `false`, but that is the opposite of what you're doing here.

Comment: Downside to setting configurable to true, is that the property can then be deleted right?

Comment: Yes. You don't have any other choice if you want to delete it at some point though.

Comment: Damn! What a conundrum.

Comment: The idea behind configurability is that you can only strengthen the restrictions, not weaken them. If there was a way to make a non-configurable property configurable, then it wouldn't provide any meaningful invariants or protection.